Unstable Release signed APK (SIGEV)
In order to comply with Google's update requirements we have been trying to generate a new version with the above release of Android studio and have encountered these problems:
The app runs in the emulator.
It run on the device by installing it through the emulator.
When creating a signed APK for RELEASE and installing it, it will crash with SIGEV error right at startup.
  Android Studio runs in these environments:
Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Build #AI-241.18034.62.2412.12266719, built on August 22, 2024 Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 x86_64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 10.14.6 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 6 Metal Rendering is ON
Same problem in this environment: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2 Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12169540, built on August 1, 2024 Runtime version: 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314 aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 14.1 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 8 Metal Rendering is ON Registry:  ide.experimental.ui=true
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!
Recompiling and creating a new APK may crash at another execution point when installed on a device.
Creating a signed APK for DEBUG may create an installable version running well.
Changing merely the apps version number and again creating a signed APK for DEBUG may give the error message 'parse error' when trying to install.
Doing the same again may create a functioning APK.
In our efforts to track down the problem we have created a NEW APP from one of the templates of Android studio and generated an APK for RELEASE - it installs fine on a device.
Changing some icons and modifying the manifest accordingly and producing a signed APK also crashed right at startup when installed on a device. No error messages at any point. Recompiling with a minimal change can produce a functioning APK.
